# Call a class function in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to call a function of a class in python but when i am trying to access the function i am unable to do that. I have started learning Python so i am not able to figure out what wrong i am doing here. Below is the python code:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
      self.name = name
      self.age = age

  def myfunc(self):
    print("Hello my name is " + self.name)
    print(self.name + " Age is :" + str(self.age))

  def addData(self):
    print("Print hello..!!!")

    p1 = Person("TestName", 36)
    p1.myfunc();
    p1.addData();
```

I want to print the age and name of the person but i am not getting any error or outpout.

Comment: The last three lines shouldn't be indented, they are at the moment part of `addData`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reformatted your code and it works:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
      self.name = name
      self.age = age

  def myfunc(self):
    print("Hello my name is " + self.name)
    print(self.name + " Age is :" + str(self.age))

  def addData(self):
    print("Print hello..!!!")

p1 = Person("TestName", 36)
p1.myfunc()
p1.addData()
```

Remember than in Python identation is very important, and also `;` is not needed at the end of lines.
In python, the semicolon is used to put several Python statements on the same line, for instance:

```
print(x); print(y); print(z)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, do you know any good tutorial from where I can learn Python

Comment: @Developer Codecademy has a good starter course, it won't teach you programming, but it will teach you Python syntax and structure quite well

Comment: Codeacademy Python 2 course it's free and really helpful to know the basics. This course introduced me to programming so yes I recommend it very much ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should instantiate an instance of the class outside the class block:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def myfunc(self):
        print("Hello my name is " + self.name)
        print(self.name + " Age is :" + str(self.age))

    def addData(self):
        print("Print hello..!!!")


p1 = Person("TestName", 36)
p1.myfunc()
p1.addData()
```